Flutter ARCore node sometimes flips to other side on vertical plain when the dots are not visible
I'm creating an AR integration in Flutter using ar_flutter_plugin.
I need to place a node on the vertical plain. When you click on the plain and the dots are visible, you can place the object as expected. Sometimes you can click on the surface when the dots are not visible. Then the node will appear flipped on the other side of the plain.
Is there a way to prevent these clicks from adding a node? I don't see any differences in the event between the 2 clicks.
This is happening on all tested Android devices.
The behavior is also when using the example project of ar_flutter_plugin.
This is not an issue on iOS.
.

